# Hide an Image and Show it

Tags: javascript, visibility

I have

```
var sanmigBottle = document.createElement('sanmigBottle');
sanmigBottle.id="sanmigBottle";
sanmigBottle.width="25%";
sanmigBottle.src='sanmigbottle.png';
sanmigBottle.onmousedown="showLibraryInfo()" ;
sanmigBottle.ontouchstart="showLibraryInfo()"  ;
sanmigBottle.align = "middle";
sanmigBottle.style= "-webkit-transform: rotate(350.77259795507035deg) translateZ(0px);'";
```

It loads in my html, however I want to hide it and I want a trigger to show. When I type this,

```
sanmigBottle.style.visibility="hidden";
```

It doesn't work. How can I do this? I am new to JS thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
sanmigBottle.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: It is still displayed. :(

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle so we can experament?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `display` to `none`:

```
sanmigBottle.style.display="none";
```

Then set it to `block` or something again to make it visible again:

```
sanmigBottle.style.display="block";
```

Comment: It is still displayed. :(

Comment: @MiguelRivera maybe you can setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? That way we can understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

First check the state of the image:

```
function showhide() {
    var img = document.getElementById('someimage');
    if (img.style.visibility === 'hidden') {
        // Currently hidden, make it visible
        img.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        // Currently visible, make it hidden
        img.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

then apply the visibility.

Answer (score -1):

try with Jquery

```
//create element
var sanmigBottle = $('<img id="sanmigBottle" width="25%" src='sanmigbottle.png' onmousedown="showLibraryInfo()" ontouchstart="showLibraryInfo()" align = "middle" style= "-webkit-transform: rotate(350.77259795507035deg) translateZ(0px);"/>');
//add to document and store object in context
var context = sanmigBottle.appendTo($('Document'));
//hide object
context.fadeOut();
```

[demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MinerBigWhale/W4CRx/3/)